# The inequalities for Krull dimension general ring R

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am recently studying the dimension theory of commutative rings, and I have encountered the problem to proof that:

> If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are two prime ideals in $R[X]$ such that $P_1 \subsetneq P_2$ and $ P_1 \cap R = P_2 \cap R= P$ then $PR[X] = P_1$.

I have been stuck by this for a while since I am not so sure what theorem to use. I have a feeling that $P_1, P_2$ can only look like $PR[X]$ and $PR[X] + (f)$, but I have no concrete idea to start with.

Comment: Something is not right here. Do you mean $P_1$ and $P_2$ are ideals of $R$? Otherwise $P_i = P_i \cap R[x] = P$ for $i=1,2$.

Comment: No, the OP obviously means that P_1 intersected with R is P and likewise for P_2.

Comment: 1) Reduce to the case $R$ is a domain and $P = 0$ (pass to $R/P$) 2) Reduce to the case $R$ is a field (pass to $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$) 3) Conclude using the fact that nonzero primes in $k[X]$ are maximal